# JavaFX стилизация кнопки "с пропущенными"

Tags: java, javafx, button

Имеется идея сделать на кнопке что-то вроде "напоминания о пропущенных" как на приложенном изображении. Как можно прицепить к кнопке такое же "оповещение"?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обязательно на кнопке ?

Comment: Да, желательно.

Answer (score 0):

У `javafx.scene.control.Button` нет списка дочерних элементов, но есть `getGraphig()`, куда можно вставить только одну ноду, поэтому вам потребуется в `graphic` кнопки вставить какой-нибудь `Pane`, например `AnchorPane` для удобства приклеивания метки к углу и внутри него реализовать зеленый фон с телефоном и `Label` с красным кругом. Тогда `Button` у вас останется с его родным `onAction()` методом на клик, а дефолтовый стиль кнопки придется убрать.